# How to create a sensible Hilbert Spectrum plot with R (computing environment)

Tags: r, plot, spectral

I am using the [EMD](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/EMD/EMD.pdf) package for R. This package has a spectrogram function for displaying a Hilbert Spectrum (calculated with hilbertspec). The output however, is really vague and black-white.

This function does not seem to have an option for outputting color images. How can I get the spectrum displayed clearly and if possible in color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gray levels are hardcoded in the `spectrogram` function (`gray()`), to override this setting you could use, for instance, the following:

```
# define a color palette
colors <- colorRampPalette(c("#007FFF", "blue", "#000077"))  
gray <- function(x) colors(255*x)  # redefine gray palette
spectrogram(test1$amplitude[,1], test1$instantfreq[,1])
gray <- grDevices::gray  # reset gray palette function
```

Another option is to use the source of the `spectrogram` function to define your own plot function which has an argument for the color palette.